# Sql mostrar dados do cliente

Tags: php, html, sql

boas, sou novo nisto e estou aqui com uma duvida. tenho um formulário com 2 campos(cliente, matricula) que quando seleciono o cliente ele dá-me o registo de veículos que esse cliente tem. Já consegui obter a informação dos veículos quando seleciono O cliente só que aparece-me todas as matriculas dos veículos registados. Como posso fazer para aparecer so as matriculas do cliente?

```
function buscaVeiculo(id) {

let resultado = document.getElementById(id).value;
let cliente = document.getElementById("txtnome").value;

var buscaVeiculo = CriaRequest();

buscaVeiculo.open("GET", "getVeiculos.php?", true);

buscaVeiculo.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (buscaVeiculo.readyState == 4) {

        if (buscaVeiculo.status == 200) {
            let respostaPHP = buscaVeiculo.responseText;
            // console.log("RETORNO PHP BUSCA FATURA >>>>> " + buscaVeiculo.responseText);
            document.getElementById("veiculo").innerHTML = buscaVeiculo.responseText;
        }
    }
}
buscaVeiculo.send(null);}
```

```
getVeiculos.php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE active=1";
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){ 
    echo "<select class='form-control' id='dropVeiculo'> ";
    echo "<option value=\"NSELECIONADO\">"  . "SELECIONE" . "</option>";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value=\"$row[matricula]\">"  . $row['matricula'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>"; 
} else{
    echo "<option>" . "SEM RESULTADOS" . "</option>";
}´´´


com este codigo que criei aparecem todas, alguem pode dar uma ajuda?

na tabela veiculos 
clieneEmpresa;
matricula

clientes
nomeClienteEmpresa
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar o id do cliente como parâmetro de query, exemplo:

Na função onde você quer pegar todas as matrículas de um cliente faça desse maneira:

```
function pegarMatriculasPeloClienteId(id){
  /* Resto do seu código */

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE active=1 AND cliente_id = " + id;

  /* Resto do seu código */     
}
```

**cliente_id é sua chave estrangeira aonde é feito o relacionamento da matricula com o cliente**

Lembrando que concatenar um parâmetro de query com a entrada de um usuário não é uma boa prática e te pode dar muita dor de cabeça no futuro, então recomendo pesquisar sobre Injeção de SQL e como contornar essa falha.

Comment: você respondeu o mesmo que eu.

Comment: Sim mas complementando algumas coisas

Answer (score -2):

Você está esquecendo de meter o `ID` ou a coluna que representa cada utilizador na sua query. Vou supor que tem cada utilizador com um ID.
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM veiculos WHERE active=1 AND ID = '<id utilizador>' ";`. Se não tem uma coluna com um ID deverá ter outra coluna que seja unica para cada utilizador.

Comment: Sim, o id do cliente na tabela cliente é igual ao clienteEmpresa na tabela veiculos.

Comment: Então é só meter ``and id = '1'`` susbtitui o ``1`` pelo id do utilizador que você quer a informação

Comment: mas assim vai aparecer sempre so os do cliente com id 1

Comment: então você não queria filtrar as matriculas por utilizador?